# Cannot resolve a symbol AppModuleNgFactory

Tags: angular, angular2-seed

I have the following import statement,

import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './app.module.ngfactory';

and it spits out an error - Cannot resolve a symbol AppModuleNgFactory.

I am using https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed for my angular 2 application.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what npm command that gives you this error?

Comment: well my tests are failing using 'npm test' command and this import statement is a part of my code from the seed project. So I think this is related to my issue of failing jasmine tests giving the following error - Failed: Invalid providers for "<ComponentName>" - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?undefined?].

Comment: I am 90% sure that the missing file is generated by AOT building. Please try to use the solution presented in my answer.

Comment: Is AppModuleNgFactory from the Angular2 Seed Project or is this your own personal module? Also, is it an Angular module or a service?

Comment: I checked. It is not in the seed itself. I believe it is generated as part of the aot process. It is however used by some of the seed files.

Comment: @BenDadsetan Do you mean, the file won't be generated unless I pass the build using the command you provided? because my build is failing for now.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you are maybe using AOT generated compiled files before having run the AOT build.

Try running

```
npm run build.prod.aot
```